# Writing script to retrieve number

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to cut the number and unit to save as number only in a file.

The input is:

```
Data byte rate:      24 bytes/s
Average packet size: 118.59 bytes
Data byte rate:      2 Kbytes/s
Average packet size: 10 Kbytes
```

the expected output is:

```
24
118.59
2000
10000
```

This is what I have done so far to retrieve only number.

```
sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+\.*[0-9]*).*?/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to do the format conversion, you could capture and preserve the optional multiplier and then pipe the result into `numfmt`

So

```
$ sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)[ \t]*([kKMGTP])?.*/\1\U\2/' input
24
118.59
2K
10K
```

which becomes

```
$ sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)[ \t]*([kKMGTP])?.*/\1\U\2/' input | numfmt --from si
24
118.59
2000
10000
```

Comment: When my input is  `Data byte rate:        2,300 bytes/s` it outputs like `2`  and another input is `71kBps` it outputs `numfmt: invalid suffix in input: '71k'`  How to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: @JessBrown for the second issue you should be able to replace `\2` by `\U\2`. The first issue will require construction of a more comprehensive regular expression.

Comment: I use `sed 's/,//g' |sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)[ \t]*([kKMGTP])?.*/\1\U\2/' input | numfmt --from si`  it works. :)